# Is there a test for tendency when ANOVA is not significant?

Tags: r, anova, trend

I have a set of data that I think shows a slight decrease in the value, but there is no statistical difference among the groups.

Is there a test to check if there is indeed a trend in the data in the absence of clear difference between groups?

The data I have is the following:

```
r0 = c(0.128, 0.131, 0.118)
r1 = c(0.128, 0.132, 0.118)
r2 = c(0.126, 0.130, 0.117)
r3 = c(0.125, 0.128, 0.115)
df = data.frame(x = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3)), y = c(r0, r1, r2, r3))
```

The plot of the data is this:

[image]

I think there is a trend for the average values decrease 0.003 units from the first to the last point:

```
0.1257 0.1260 0.1243 0.1227
```

But the ANOVA test is of course not significant:

```
> oneway.test(y ~ x, data = df, var.equal = TRUE)

    One-way analysis of means

data:  y and x
F = 0.1458, num df = 3, denom df = 8, p-value = 0.9295
```

Is there a test that could tell me if the trend is real or just wishful thinking?

Thank you

Comment: Sure, a linear model (assuming your x variable is at least ordinal).

Comment: Can the observations be matched in any way?  It looks like the third element in each vector is less than the other two, is there a reason for that related to the experimental design?

Comment: What is x?  What is the DV?  Is x ordinal? A count? Continuous?

Comment: The biggest issue I see here is that the confidence intervals are so wide that they indicate very miniscule differences across groups when considering population values.

Comment: What do the $1,2,3,4$ mean, real numbers or just the group labels that could have been “cat”, “dog”, “horse”, and “piranha”?

Comment: x is ordinal (increasing concentration of a reagent). The measurements were done in three different days.

Comment: Do you have the actual concentration values, not just the ordering?

Comment: Also, why do you think there should be statistical significance when the hypothesis test says otherwise? In some sense, the point of doing formal tests is to bring quantitative rigor to the analysis process and not just let analysts eyeball charts and go, “Yep, looks downward,” when there is so much uncertainty that such a claim has a real chance to be incorrect. (One of my grad school mentors got a kick of of seeing seemingly impressive results, asking if those results were statistically significant, and getting responses that, no, there is too much uncertainty to get significance.)

Comment: p = 0.9295 is wishful thinking, period.

Comment: I see the point, but what about the Cochran–Armitage test for trend, for instance? Anyway, the actual concentrations as: 1=0, 2=0.6, 3=1.2, 4=2.5. Thanks